# Извлечение названия песни регулярным выражением

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день. Плохо разбираюсь в регулярных выражениях. Помогите доделать.

Данный код берёт текст с сайта, а именно страницы - http://best-muzon.ru/lastnews/
Нужно вырезать только названия песен, но с моей регуляркой, он выводит только часть песен.

Есть код -

```
 $skrap = parser ($host,$path,$start,$end,$include);
    if ($skrap) {
      // Заменить теги переноса строки на простые переносы строки
      $grab=str_replace("<br>","\n",$grab);
      // Получить регулярным выражением тексты цитат
      preg_match_all("/<div id=\"shrt\">([^>]*>){12}([^<]*)/",$skrap,$matches);
      // В массиве содержатся все найденные строки
      for ($i=0; $i<count($matches[2]); $i++) {
        echo '<a href="/mp3/'.nl2br($matches[2][$i]).'">'.nl2br($matches[2][$i]).'</a>';
        echo '<br>';
      }
    }
```

Comment: Ещё также, после вывода, пишет Array ,как избавиться?

Comment: Приведите кусок текста, который надо распарсить и желаемый результат из этого текста.

Answer (score 1):

Говоришь **только** названия, но при этом тянешь всю ссылку?

Получаем **только названия**

```
/<div\sid=\"shrt\"><img\s.*?/>\r\n<a\shref=\".*?\"\stitle=\".*?\">(.*?)</a>\r\n</div>/
```

Грубо, но попробуй.
возможно надо будет удалить rn. Проверял в Notepad++

По поводу Array, попробуй

```
var_dump($var)
```

Посмотри что за массив.

Comment: ИМХО `print_r` рулит =)

Comment: О вкусах не спорят.

Comment: Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown modifier '>' in D:\Webwork\webserver\domains\music.os\www\index.php on line 442

Такая ошибка получается с вашим примером

Comment: `>` экранировать надо.

Comment: Как экранировать, я так понимаю в ковычки, но ошибка появляется другая